# Use Laravel 5 Illuminate\Html without Composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ok, I need to use the Illuminate\Html package WITHOUT composer.

I'm using Plesk, which has php 5.3 installed by default. I managed to add another version of PHP (5.5) using fastcgi to run side by side. This allowed me to install Laravel (since it didn't play well with 5.3).

I've finally got it all setup and working, but now when I try to install `Illuminate\Html` to access the Form Facade, I'm getting the error message:

```
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 6466:
Class 'illuminate\html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

I installed composer, but because Plesk runs PHP 5.3 by default, and composer runs default php, I get the following errors:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for illuminate/html 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/html[v5.0.0].
    - illuminate/html v5.0.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - league/flysystem 1.0.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for league/flysystem == 1.0.2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

All I'm getting is error after error after error.

How can I get Illuminate\HTML to work, without requiring the use of composer? I've Googled and every page I go to tells me to run composer update.

I've added the following to app.php

```
'providers' => [
...
   'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'
```

and

```
'aliases' => [
...
    'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
    'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade'
```

I've checked that Illuminate\Html is on the server, which is it, in the Vendor directory.

What else do I need to do?

Thanks, and if I can provide more information, please let me know.

**EDIT**

Extra information:

- I cannot upgrade directly to php 5.5 from 5.3 because plesk does not
  allow me to do this.
- I have had to use plesk php panda to install additional PHP versions which run as FastCGI modules
- PHP 5.3 runs on the server as the apache module default.
- I have access to php 5.5 and php 5.6 on the same server.

Comment: I would recommend getting Plex to run on PHP 5.5, because you will really wish you had composer working when developing later in Laravel.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant. Plesk required PHP 5.3 to run it's software. I have php 5.5 and php 5.6 running as fastcgi modules, but I don't know how to specify that composer run these versions instead of the default 5.3 version. On my work servers, I am able to use composer, it's just the crappy Plesk / php5.3 that's causing major issues for me.

Comment: Have you tried changing the path to the PHP version in your bash profile?

Comment: I will attempt to, but I only know the very basics of linux... It's cheaper than windows. Thankfully it's only for a personal site, so there's no urgency. Thanks for your comments though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run composer with a flag to ignore system requirements such as your php version.

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

From the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update)

> **--ignore-platform-reqs**: ignore `php`, `hhvm`, `lib-*` and `ext-*` requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate the answer, and also the simplicity of the answer!